# How to track engagement and people into mixpanel with one call

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

This is mixpanel question.

I need to track engagement and people param in one call.

```
<script>
function signupFunc(){
     mixpanel.people.set({
        "$email": "hoge@email.com",
        "vpc":0
    });
</script>
<script>
mixpanel.identify("11111");
mixpanel.people.increment("vpc", 1);
mixpanel.track("View Page");
</script>
```

Comment: By same timing do you mean combining `mixpanel.people.increment("vpc", 1);` and `mixpanel.track("View Page");` into one call?

Comment: yes. I want to call into one call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update the user profile property and trigger the event in a single Mixpanel call.

Instead you can use a wrapper function like this:

```
function trackEvent(eventName, eventData){
    mixpanel.track(eventName, eventData);
    mixpanel.people.increment("eventCount - " + eventName, 1);
}

trackEvent("View Page", {});
```

The user profile will then have a property called "eventCount - View Page")